# Calling function by value of variable

Tags: java, scala, playframework

All is in the title.
Exemple of what i want in php:

```
function x($name){
 echo 'hello'.$name;
}

$var = "x";

$$var('Joe');
```

return "Joe"

I think this question as already many answers but i can't find the right word to spell it so my search queries are pointless...

Thanks

*edit: i'm using scala with play framework and i want to call different template based on the user agent.
in play i call a template using :*

```
Ok(views.html.templateFileName(many args))
```

*i search a way to do:*

```
Ok(views.html.<Template name based on user agent>(many args))
```

Comment: So, is this a php, java or scala question?  Also, what is your question?

Comment: this is not possible in Java. What is the business requirement you are trying to solve?

Comment: This *is* possible in Java or Scala using reflection, but there is most likely a better way to do what you *actually* want to do. As Timothy said, what is the reason why you think you need this?

Comment: thanks for interests, i've just updated my post

Comment: You should be able to obtain the User Agent header from the request. Please add more relevant code related to Play.

Comment: it's not about how to get the user agent. in play! framework views are treated as class. and while they can have lots of args i wan't to dynamically build the class name to avoid rewriting code with a if/else ...

Answer (score 1):

Using reflection you can do this but the syntax is very verbose.

Lets declare a class called as `Foo` and declare a method inside called `bar` which takes a Integer argument and returns Integer

Usually we invoke the method like this `foo.bar(1)` where `foo` is the object reference of `Foo` class.

Now lets invoke the method using the name of the method which is `bar`.

```
class Foo {
  def bar(x: Integer): Int = x * x
}

val result = classOf[Foo].getDeclaredMethod("bar", classOf[Integer]).invoke(new Foo, new Integer(1))
```

**REPL output**

```
@ class Foo {
    def bar(x: Integer): Int = x * x
  }
defined class Foo
@
@ val result = classOf[Foo].getDeclaredMethod("bar", classOf[Integer]).invoke(new Foo, new Integer(1))
result: Object = 1
```